# How can I implement Yondu's Yaka Arrow?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, weapons, homebrew

I'm a neophyte DM and currently running a homebrew. One player in the group wants to incorporate the Yaka Arrow from Guardians of the Galaxy (as seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TiJ2aTDa7RQ)).

How I should implement it and is there any restrictions I should apply?

Comment: Welcome to the rpg stack! As written this may be too broad as it's asking for ideas. We can certainly review homebrew content but not asking for homebrew ideas, I'm afraid. Once you do have some implementation in mind, you can ask about it here. Good luck and happy gaming!

Comment: I think it may be more on point to ask *If something like the yaka arrow from the Guardians of the Galaxy film franchise doesn't exist, how can be simulated?* (There are an *amazing* number of options in *3.5* for the open-minded campaign—assuming something can't be done usually leads to someone proving you wrong.) Then, if need be, craft your own and in a new question ask about any balance concerns.

Comment: do you want this item to be disarmable (able to be taken away)?

Comment: Homebrew or reskinned official materials?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it will result in something exactly like that but in 3.5 book Complete Psionic  you have a psionic power called Living Arrow that do this:

> When you manifest living arrow, you give a semblance of life to the projectiles you shoot at your foes. The power affects the first projectile you fire each round, granting it limited sentience and the ability to alter its course in mid-flight.
>
> You can launch a living arrow at a target known to you within the maximum range of the weapon. The living arrow travels to the target, even around corners. Only an unavoidable obstacle or the limit of the arrow's range prevents the arrow from reaching its target.

So, I think that with you combine that power feats for ricocheting or attacking more than one target you can do something similar and not as overwhelming as the actual Yaka Arrow.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable start to an answer to me, but it would be helpful if you could expand on it. As is, it just recommends a power that comes vaguely close for the right character class. Could this be made to fit into an item so it isn't constrained to a character power? What level and balancing are involved? Would any refluffing be needed?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.